# Getting data from the Service to the Activity

Tags: android

In my application I have a service in which rss feeds are read. After the service finishes the reading I need to update my application and populate a list view with the downloaded information. Using a broadcast receiver, and intents would not work, because the data is stored in a custom object. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using a broadcast receiver, and intents would not work, because the data is stored in a custom object.

Then don't store the data in "a custom object".

> What is the best way to do that?

Step #1: Use a database.

Step #2: Alert the activity that there is new data in the database, via a broadcast `Intent`, or via a `Messenger` passed into the service, or via a `PendingIntent` created by `createPendingResult()` passed into the service, or via a `ContentProvider` facade and a content observer, etc.

Step #3: Have the activity load the data out of the database, perhaps simply by calling `requery()` on an outstanding `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

1) The simplest way to get Custom class data in Intent is, Get the data to primitive types then put this data by putString or whatever data type, then add a constructor to corresponding sent data to activity from set in custom object in activity.

2) Other way of doing this is extend your custom class by parcelable and override corresponding methods then you will be able to send parcelable class object with intent.
go to this link [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-with-intent-putextra) for details